# If select "connect even if the network is not broadcasting", if router is malfunctioning, will that slow down internet?

Tags: internet, wireless-router

I rent a cottage on land, we all share internet via same router. (wireless) But often, router blinks off, been long-term problem. Sometimes stays off a couple days. So, I'm wondering whether to check that box "connect even if the network is not broadcasting". Router is always broadcasting IF it's actually working. (It's never set to hide itself.) I'm just wondering which option would be better in my situation:
I could see a disadvantage either way, but am not sure that's how it really works:

1. Possible disadvantage if unchecked?: if router blinks off, then back on five minutes later, my PC may not keep trying to connect to it, and won't know when it's back on, so will stay disconnected?
   OR
2. Possible disadvantage if checked?: if router is dead for the whole weekend, and nobody knows, my PC may keep trying to connect, wasting its precious internet speed which could be used connecting to my neighbour's router instead? (my neighbour's always works, but he's further away so not my first choice.)

Basically, I want to avoid squandering internet speed, which I can't afford, as it's always slow out here where I live!

Can anyone please advise me as to the wisest choice and explain?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem doesn't have anything to do with checking or unchecking that box.

That option only tries to keep you connected even when the router's SSID is hidden.

On Windows, there is always an option to "connect automatically" whenever you want to connect to a wireless network.  That should be your best option. This attempts to connect whenever the wireless signal starts broadcasting. Even if it keeps "blinking" (as u say) every 5 minutes.

You say the router sometimes goes off, if you have access to the router, you could just pull the plug and restart. This comes in handy for some of the popular linksys/home routers. Hopefully, the connection will be restored.

Alternatively, if you have access to the administrative part of the router, changing the wireless channel could do a lot of good. There might be some overlapping network somewhere on the same channel with this very router's signal. Channels 1,6,11 are good options to switch between. I'm sure this would help fix things.

But I don't advice you keeping the "connect even if not broadcasting" option checked. Don't.